# AWS CodeDeploy Appspec.yml files are not being copied to destination

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-code-deploy-appspec

My files are properly copied to an EC2 instance for deployments, but they are not copied to the destination. I've got at appspec.yml file like this:

```
ubuntu@ip:~$ cat /opt/coded*/deployment-root/*/*/de*/appspec.yml
version: 0.0
os: linux
# I also tried with source: /
files:
  - source: .
    destination: /home/ubuntu/
file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
# notes

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# To learn more about hooks, visit the docs here:
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html#appspec-hooks-server
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_dependencies
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start_server
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/stop_server
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

**I've also tried setting source to source: / with the same result; nothing's copied**

And I see my files are all in that /opt/coded* etc. path. But why isn't the CodeDeploy agent copying my files to the destination? The Download bundle hook is good, and the only error I get is in the ApplicationStart hook when I need to actually access my files.

Note: I'm using GitHub as my revision storage, not S3, if that helps

Edit: something that might be useful to know is in my install_dependencies script, I run something along the lines of:

```
cd /home/ubuntu/
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

where the pip installation is the line where it can't find the files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reasoning: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-example.html#appspec-file-example-server

The order of the hooks. The files are copied before the AfterInstall hook.